# Is formatting required to compare dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2016-03-31' > (SELECT MAX(year) from table where bill_id = 'somevalue')
```

I am using above query to check if 2016-03-31 is **greater than** all years present in table against bill_id. It is working fine. but is it correct approach to compare dates. dates will always in above format. Is there any need to **convert date format for comparison**. value 2016-03-31 will change dynamically but it will be always in Y-m-d format

**Note : year is column name which contains full date in Y-m-d format like 2016-05-20**

Comment: as far as I know, it'll be better and faster to compare just the year with the year. That way MySQL doesn't have to do anything with your input before comparing it to the output of `MAX(year)`

Comment: year column have full value in Y-m-d format

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're asking if you must convert date columns to string to compare (you shouldn't) or if the date literal is configurable (it isn't). But here you aren't doing date maths, for MySQL it's just a couple of strings.

Comment: @hrishi In that case this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing dates. You are comparing a string `'2016-03-31'` with a number, e.g. `2015`.

In order to compare, MySQL silently converts the string to number. One would expect this to crash, as `'2016-03-31'` certainly isn't a number. MySQL, however, reads from left to right and takes from there all that can be considered a number, i.e. `'2016'`. Well, one could argue that some people put a minus sign at the end of a number, so this should be `'2016-'`, i.e. `-2016`. Anyway, MySQL stops before the minus sign, gets `2016` and uses this for the comparision.

**I don't know if all this is guaranteed to work in the future. I would not rely on this.**

What result would you expect anyway? Is the 31st of March 2016 greater than the year 2016? That's a queer question, don't you think?

Comment: Column year contains full date in Y-m-d format like 2016-03-31. so you can say it compares  2016-03-31 with dates in DB like 2015-05-30, 2014-03-31

Comment: Okay, so I misread your question. You chose a very bad column name which makes your query almost unreadable, as you see from my interpretation. So `year` doesn't contain a year, but a date string. As this string always contains yyyy-mm-dd and you compare it with a string of the same format, you can do so without problem. Apart from naming the date string `year` it is also strange that you use a string type rather than a date type. This makes it possible to mistakenly store '2015-055-30' and the like. But well, as long as `year` does contain a valid yyyy-mm-dd date,your query is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But do you really have a column `year` that stores only year?

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE year(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-31')) 
> (SELECT MAX(year) from table where bill_id = 'somevalue')
```

Comment: Column year contains full date in Y-m-d format like 2016-03-31

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR('2016-03-31') > (SELECT MAX(year) from table where bill_id = 'somevalue')
```

MySQL YEAR() returns the year for a given date or timestamp. The return value is in the range of 1000 to 9999 or 0 for 'zero' date.